# Cassandra: Is there a relation between TombstoneOverwhelmingException by READSTAGE and a broken pipe exception?

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra System Log:

```
ERROR [ReadStage:8468] 2016-05-09 08:58:28,029 SliceQueryFilter.java (line 206) Scanned over 100000 tombstones in AAAAA.EVENT_QUEUE_DATA; query aborted (see tombstone_failure_threshold)
ERROR [ReadStage:8468] 2016-05-09 08:58:28,029 CassandraDaemon.java (line 258) Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:8468,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.TombstoneOverwhelmingException
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2008)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Application Log:

```
! java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
! at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
! at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
! at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
! at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

I don't know the exact cause for this yet. My guess is a trigger of many delete calls to Cassandra might have caused this situation. Any advise would be very helpful to me at this moment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A temp workaround, you can increase `tombstone_failure_threshold` in `cassandra.yaml`.

I guess from the `AAAAA.EVENT_QUEUE_DATA` name is that you've implemented a queue. This is an [anti-pattern](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets) which also would cause exactly what your explaining. This will continue to get bad and cause a lot of GC style issues and performance problems down the road.

Knowing that doesn't really help you today though. I would suggest you increase your failure threshold (above) and update your [compaction strategy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/compactSubprop.html) to help in future. Heres an idea:

```
ALTER TABLE footable WITH
  compaction = {'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy', 
    'sstable_size_in_mb': '256mb',
    'tombstone_compaction_interval': '14400',
    'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'true',
    'tombstone_threshold': '0.05'} AND 
  gc_grace_seconds = 14400  # assuming you will use everything in queue within this window of seconds
```

But you will want to make changes in your application. Keep in mind that more aggressive tombstone removal creates a possibility for a delete to be "lost" but its not very likely and is better than being down.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We are trying to put a delay in the delete writes/write deletes in small blocks instead of one big block to Cassandra. lets see if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Tombstones are generated when you "delete" your data and they represent logical markers for delete functionality. This is a part of a mechanism which helps you fight ghost columns. If you deleted a lot of data you can easily hit tombstone warning and even error (like in your case). There is a gc_grace period setting on your table which defines retention time for tombstones. Also, try to avoid selecting everything (make select statements target actual data instead of range queries).